# Angular 8 Jasmine Karma: TypeError: Cannot read property 'abiertos' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Estaba desarrollando una App en *Angular 8 con TypeScript* como lenguaje de Script, y me ha surgido el siguiente error testeando uno de los componentes.

> EscaparateTerminalesComponent > abiertos defaults to: []
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'abiertos' of undefined

El código de mi componente sería el siguiente:

```
export class EscaparateTerminalesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...

  cerrarCaracMov() {
    // console.log('titulos', this.titulos);
    for (let e = 0; e < this.titulos.length; e++) {
      this.abiertos.push(false);
    }
    // console.log(this.abiertos);
  }

  caerrarAbrirCarac(i) {
    if (this.abiertos[i] === false) {
      this.abiertos[i] = true;
    } else {
      this.abiertos[i] = false;
    }
    for (let t = 0; t < this.titulos.length; t++) {
      if (this.abiertos[t] !== true) {
        this.abiertos[t] = false;
      }
    }
...
}
```

Y el código correspondiente al archivo **`spec.ts`** sería el que podéis ver a continuación debajo de vuestras pantallas justo aquí debajo de esta línea de aquí:

```
  it('abiertos defaults to: []', () => {
    expect(component.abiertos).toEqual([]);
  });
```

Espero podáis ayudar en el caso de que sepáis por donde van los tiros, y si ese es el caso, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes declarar tu variable abiertos como vacío

`public abiertos:any[] = []`